Server-sent events (SSE) aren't streamed in AWS ECS with Service Connect enabled for the task
I have a backend service that proxies STREAM from LLM to a frontend. Therefore, the frontend uses SSE to show a result dynamically - a typical scenario.
Running locally and being deployed on ECS Fargate the streaming works smoothly. But, after, the Service Connect is enabled for the task, streaming gets sort of buffered returning only the entire LLM result at once.
No buffering is used in the code, as it's said it works already as is.
    @PostMapping(value = "/completions", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> complete(@Valid @RequestBody CompletionRequest request) {
        return goApiWebClient.post()
                .uri("/v1/chat/completions")
                .bodyValue(completionRequest)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(String.class)
                .takeWhile(response -> !response.equals("[DONE]"))
                .onErrorResume(e -> Flux.just("Error while calling ChatGPT API: " + e.getMessage()));
    }

I've tried to search and ask ChatGPT. They advice to disable buffering for some routes in the envoy config. But problem is I use fargate have no clue how to reach this config.

Hi Sarkhad,
I'm facing to the very same issue. How did you manage to solve this ?

@user1458153 I stopped using AWS' API Gateway and connected directly through ALB. Service Connect works fine in this case.

thanks a lot Sarkhad.
I finally made it work by modifying the 'no answer timeout' in the Service Connect configuration (15 sec by default -> I had to set 3600 for instance). It means that the  envoy proxy does not seem to understand that my proxied service actually responded something, and that is a bit annoying, no ?
